# Google spreadsheet - Error when Remove range protection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, protected, named-ranges

Here's my script, but I can't get it to work for some weird reason??!!!  Driving me nuts.

```
function removeThenSetProtection() {
  // Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet that the user has
  //permission to edit.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);

  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code worked for me.  I set a protected range manually, ran your code, and it removed the protection.  We need to have more info.  Who is running the script?  A user other than you?  If so, what are their permissions?  Also, use `Logger.log('Variable Name: ' + variableName)` statements, and then VIEW the LOGS.  Or step through your code line by line with the Debugger.    [Troubleshooting - Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: Is the spreadsheet actually open when the code is run?  Is the sheet that you want to act on, the active sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
```

To:

```
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
```

That way, you'll be assured that you are getting a reference to everything that is protected, and future conflicts don't happen.